# Is it possible to get sizeof from a function?

Tags: c++

I call a function like this:

```
void do_work(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    //do things with ptr and size
}
```

The question is: is it possible to call the function like `do_work(one);` and somehow get the sizeof inside the function?

Given `one` is **a static array** (`int one[10];`) or **non array** (`int one;`), is it possible now?

Comment: What is the function's signature?

Comment: What do you mean by signature?

Comment: The function takes one `void*` and one `size_t` as input.

Comment: Then no, you can't get the size inside of the function.

Comment: Please provide the declaration of the function in the question. And, given that input (a pointer) the answer is no.

Comment: is this a C or C++ question?

Comment: C++, I edited the tags.

Comment: What do you mean "get the sizeof inside the function"? `sizeof` of what?What's `one`?

Comment: one is a pointer to anything. e.g. `char one[10];`

Comment: There might be platform specific function which allows you to get the size of some memory, *if it was allocated dynamically*, but there's nothing in the C or C++ standards that allow you to get the size from a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void do_work(T* stuff)
{
  const size_t s = sizeof(T);
  ....
}
```

**Edit**: version for arrays:

```
template<typename T, size_t N >
void do_work(T (&array)[N] )
{
  const size_t s = N * sizeof(T);
}
```

Comment: in the case of `int one[10]` this returns 4. I want it to return 40, is this possible?

Comment: @Luka You could write a template that takes arrays. I added an example.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you could use template argumment deduction to get the type of the pointer (the pointed type) and then compute its sizeof:

```
template<typename T>
void do_work( T* ptr )
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof(T);
}
```

Comment: Neat answer! Not to go off a tangent, but will sizeof(T) produce reliable results when T is non-POD type?

Comment: @DigitalEye Well, if `T` is not a POD type, could be a problem (`sizeof()` doesn't return what we expect), like issues with the vptr on polymorphic classes, padding, etc. But thats not really a problem, `sizeof()` only does what is dessigned for, compute the size of an instance of the type, right? Its you, as user, what have to be carefull with what you expect and its results. However, given the assigment (A function that takes a `void*`, and a size), I supposed that its a function related to working with PODs, like `memcpy()`ing, etc.

Comment: @DigitalEye You could always use type traits and SFINAE if that details are a problem.

Answer (score 3):

No, not for `void *`, you will not be able to compute the size of the object whose address is passed.

Comment: Is there no way? using templates somehow? I feel like I am in the pre-function era...

Comment: sorry for messing up the tags

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
void do_work(T* ptr)
{
    size_t size = sizeof(T);
    size = sizeof(*ptr); // or this
}
```

Comment: How is the first C++11? You couldn't do `sizeof(type)` before C++11?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oh sorry your right. I apparently mixed things up with `typeid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
void do_work(T * t) { do_work(t, sizeof(T)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C++, this question appeared before me, probably because it previously had the C tag. But here's something that you could do in C, probably also in C++:

```
#define do_work(_a_) do_work_func(_a_, sizeof(_a_))

void do_work_func( void* ptr, size_t size )
{
    //do things with ptr and size
}
```

Which would work out, given that `one` in `do_work( one );` call had been defined as an array.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you might want:

```
#include <iostream>

void do_work(void* ptr, size_t size)
{
    std::cout << "Size: " << size << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
void do_work(T& single) {
    do_work(&single, 1);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void do_work(T (&array)[N]) {
    do_work(array, N);
}

template <typename T>
void do_work(T* multiple, std::size_t n) {
    do_work(static_cast<void*>(multiple), n);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int* c = b;
    do_work(a);
    do_work(b);
    do_work(c, 3);
}
```

Note: Why the void* ?